# Redux toolkit thunk disappears after getDefaultMiddlware config

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit, thunk

My store looks like this:

```
export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    sequencer: sequencerReducer,
    editMode: editModeReducer,
    tone: toneReducer,
    app: appReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
    getDefaultMiddleware({ immutableCheck: false });
  },
});
```

I had a working thunk, but I need this `immutableCheck: false` config. Once set it seems to overwrite the default middleware and thunk is no longer working.  Here is my thunk:

```
export const modCell = (step, noteOn) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const selectedSound = getState().editMode.selectedSound;
  dispatch(sequencerSlice.actions.toggleCell({ step, selectedSound }));
};
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show the thunk you're trying to dispatch, and _how_ you're dispatching it?  Also, _why_ do you need to turn off the immutability check?

Comment: @markerikson Just updated with the thunk.  This is defined in one of the reducers (sequencerSlice). I have the imm. check turned off because I am building a drum sequencer with thousands of state properties deeply nested.  The check makes using the app way too slow.

Comment: Hmm. Unrelated to this issue, but can you comment in https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/926 and leave a link to either your actual project repo or put together a sandbox/repo that mimics your current setup? I want to improve the immutability check perf, and this sounds like it would be a good stress test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see the issue. Your `middleware` function isn't *returning* anything.  You have curly braces with that `middleware` arrow function, so it's a function body with no implicit return. You either need to add an explicit `return` statement, or change it to an implicit return by removing the curly braces.  So, you're ending up with no middleware setup at all.

*edit*

To be clear, what you want is:

```js
export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    sequencer: sequencerReducer,
    editMode: editModeReducer,
    tone: toneReducer,
    app: appReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
    return getDefaultMiddleware({ immutableCheck: false });
  },
});
```

Comment: `middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {   getDefaultMiddleware({ immutableCheck: false });  },` should become `middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {   return getDefaultMiddleware({ immutableCheck: false });  },` or `middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({ immutableCheck: false }),`